# Scope error in arduino PinChangeInt library

Tags: arduino-uno

```
#include<PinChangeInt.h>
#define SensorPin 2

int ledPin = 10;
int BuzzerPin = 12;
volatile byte blip = 0;

void blipcount(){
  blip++;
};

void setup() {
   // put your setup code here, to run once:
   pinMode(SensorPin,INPUT);
   pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(BuzzerPin,OUTPUT);
   PCintPort::attachInterrupt(SensorPin,blipCount,FALLING);
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
   if(digitalRead(SensorPin)==HIGH){
      digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(BuzzerPin,HIGH);
      Serial.print("blipcoun:\t");
      Serial.println(blip,DEC);
   }

   if(digitalRead(SensorPin)==LOW){
      digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
      digitalWrite(BuzzerPin,LOW);
   }
}
```

I am using arduino uno for a project.I need to record when my sensor gives a high value but i need it to read only falls in pulses.The program is giving  error as

```
Arduino: 1.6.3 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Sense.ino: In function 'void setup()':

Sense.ino:14:38: error: 'blipCount' was not declared in this scope

Error compiling
```

please tell me what is the problem with the function.

The library link is 
https://code.google.com/p/arduino-pinchangeint/downloads/list

tested the code on both 1.72 and 2.19

Comment: `void blipcount(){
  blip++;
};` why the `;` at the end of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
PCintPort::attachInterrupt(SensorPin,blipCount,FALLING);
```

Should be:

```
PCintPort::attachInterrupt(SensorPin,blipcount,FALLING);
                                         ^
```

Note the lower-case "c".